# Rspec Controller tests, passing JSON params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, testing, rspec, controller

I'm trying to achieve the following: create a POST json request within RSpec Controller test, passing it params. Here's my code

```
it 'returns access_token' do
    post :login, email: 'bla', password: 'bla1', format: :json
end
```

What I get in controllers request.body.read is a string with params, but passed like this
  `email=bla&password=bla1`

This is definitely not a JSON. But, if I make request using CURL

`curl -d '{"email": "bla@bla.com" }' http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json"`

I get my request.body.read as a correct json

`"{\"email\": \"bla@bla.com\", \"password\": \"bla1\" }"`

So how do I pass it this way from my rspec?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
post "/models/#{@model.id}",
        params: {
            some_field: "1234",
        },
        as: :json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass header in your RSpec file.

```
header "Content-Type", "application/json"
post :something
```

And you can pass params like this :

```
post :create, :object => { :email => email,
                           ...
                         }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for response. Actually it's pretty same, because format: :json sets all headers.