# Getting a status 400 (BadRequest) with jsonapi(0.9.0) on Rails 5 using Rspec-rails(3.0) request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I have a strange situation where a postman or curl post, work just fine, e.g below works as expected and creates a new record:

```
curl -X POST \                                   
  -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" \
  -d '{
  "data": {
    "type": "drivers",
    "attributes": {
      "firstname": "John",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "age": "24",
      "status": "pending"
    }
  }
}' "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/drivers"
```

but when I try to get to it via RSpec request spec as below, this gives me a status 400 (BadRequest):

```
...
describe "POST /api/v1/drivers" do
  context 'valid data' do 
    it 'saves valid data' do
      headers = { 
        "Content-Type" => "application/vnd.api+json",
        "Accept" => "application/vnd.api+json " 
      }

      post api_v1_drivers_path, params: {
        data: {
          type: 'drivers',
          attributes: {
            firstname: 'John',
            lastname: 'Doe',
            age: 24,
            status: 'pending'
          }
        }
      }, headers: headers

      expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
    end
  end
end
```

Have you come across this issue? something obvious I am missing? any feedback is very welcome.

Comment: I am not sure but what if you converted the params to json? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016140/rspec-controller-tests-passing-json-params#29016649)

Comment: Do you have `params` permitting in the controller? If yes, try to inspect `params` in both cases

Comment: If error is throwing before you can do inspect, use @JollyProgrammer advise

Comment: @JollyProgrammer adding .to_json did fix it :) +1

Comment: nice to know :)

Answer (score 0):

converting params to json did the trick, thanks to @JollyProgrammer:

```
post api_v1_drivers_path, params: {
   data: {
     type: 'drivers',
     attributes: {
       firstname: 'John',
       lastname: 'Doe',
       age: 24,
       status: 'pending'
     }
   }
}, as: :json, headers: headers
```